# Spring parent container

Tags: java, spring

I came up with the `parent/child`-container concept. I have the spring's param defined in `web.xml` file as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-site-dao.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-site-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-mailing.xml
        classpath:**/applicationContext-*.xml
        classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext-*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is that configuration is going to create 5 child containers of 1 big parent container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your asking about a `context-param`, I'm going to assume you're asking about the `ContextLoaderListener`.

The `ContextLoaderListener` will create a single `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` and use its [`ConfigurableWebApplicationContext#setConfigLocation(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html#setConfigLocation-java.lang.String-) method to set the configuration location(s), separated by white space.

This is a single Spring container (`ApplicationContext`). It has no parents.

Spring will then create another `WebApplicationContext` through the `DispatcherServlet` which will use the `ContextLoaderListener`'s as a parent.

Comment: So, in our projects we don't use parent/child containers. Could you explain in a nutshell why we would use that facility ever?

Comment: The `DispatcherServlet` does. There are beans, like bean post processors, that only apply to the container in which they are defined.